# PHP mysqli_prepare is not supporting lock statements?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, locking

I try to lock the whole table.

Using the following codes:
Issues: the if statement never print true, If I change to some other select statement with $sql, it works

```
$link = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
$sql = "lock table tableA write";
if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql))
    echo "true";
```

*Also for testing, there are no other codes in my php other these.
Also I checked the user, has

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, LOCK TABLES ON *.* TO 'user'@'localhost'
```

I can not figure it out... and I am new to mysql with PHP as well..
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Edit: after added mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

it shows the error message:

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: This command is not supported in the prepared statement protocol yet in /var/www/html/x.php:27
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/x.php(27): mysqli_prepare(Object(mysqli), 'lock table tableA...')
#1 {main}
thrown in /var/www/html/x.php on line 27

I found the solution.. you can call it directly with mysqli_query(..) since mysqli_prepare does not support locking.

```
if(mysqli_query($link,$sql)){
    echo "true";
}
```

Comment: What is the error message? Did you enable error reporting? [How to get the error message in MySQLi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439)

Comment: I have few other php files with mysqli, they works fine, but this is the first time with locking, So I do not want to update other files for now.

Comment: I updated the question, why stackoverflow considers this is a duplicated of a different questions...

Comment: Because the duplicate gave you the answer you needed. The message is now clear and correct, isn't it? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html#prepared-statements-permitted You can't use `LOCK TABLE` in Prepared statements

Comment: Thanks Dharman, the error message helps a lot.